# NodeJS return SQL queries to pass to another file

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, return-value

I have been struggling with the **returning of data** for the past 2 days. I really need help in getting the data to show **in another .js file** but I can't seem to do so.

From all the research I have done, I know that I need the callback function in order to do the return. When I output the data in **file1.js**, it shows, which is correct.

However, I need to access the returned data in my **file2.js** but it is not showing.
Am I missing anything out?  Please help, any response is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Note that my return statement in **file1.js** is near the end of the code.
Also, my "res" array is ALWAYS empty when accessed outside the function. Why is this so?

file1.js

```js
var sql = require("mssql");

// Create a configuration object for our Azure SQL connection parameters
var dbConfig = {
 server: "***", // Use your SQL server name
 database: "***", // Database to connect to
 user: "***", // Use your username
 password: "***", // Use your password
 port: 1433,
 // Since we're on Windows Azure, we need to set the following options
 options: {
       encrypt: true
   }
};

var obj = {};
var res = [];

// This function connects to a SQL server, executes a SELECT statement,
// and displays the results in the console.
function getProducts(callback) {
 // Create connection instance
 var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

 conn.connect()
 // Successfull connection
 .then(function () {

   // Create request instance, passing in connection instance
   var req = new sql.Request(conn);

   // Call mssql's query method passing in params
   req.query("SELECT sp.product_name, count(ss.product_id) as 'quantity' " +
      "FROM smartcoolerstocks ss JOIN smartcoolerproducts sp " +
      "ON sp.product_id = ss.product_id " +
      "GROUP by sp.product_name ")
   .then(function (recordset) {
     //console.log(recordset.recordset);
     
     conn.close();
     //NEED CALLBACK FUNCTION
     console.log(recordset.recordset.length);

      for(var i = 0; i<recordset.recordset.length; i++ ){     
                    res.push(recordset.recordset[i]);
        }
     
     
     callback(null,recordset.recordset);
     process.exit(1);
   })
   // Handle sql statement execution errors
   .catch(function (err) {
     console.log(err);
     conn.close();
   })

 })
 // Handle connection errors
 .catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   conn.close();
 });
 
}



//call Fn for db query with callback
getProducts(function(err,data){
        if (err) {
            // error handling code goes here
            console.log("ERROR : ",err);            
        } else {            
            // code to execute on data retrieval
            //console.log("result from db is : ",data.recordset);   
            //return data.recordset;
            return res;                
            
        }
        
});
console.log(res); //WHY IS THIS EMPTY HERE?



module.exports = {
  getProducts(){},
  
};
```

> Blockquote

file2.js

```js
var myDB2 = require('./sqltest2');


console.log(myDB2.getProducts());
```

Here's my output in cmd:
[image]

After the '7', there's nothing showing.

My IDEAL output should be the following if I manage to get the returned data in file2.js from file1.js:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot see the `res` because its race condition, your `console.log(res)`  executed earlier than `recordset` callback.
2. `file1.js` already executed the getProducts function so there is not data that returned to `file2.js`.

```js
var sql = require("mssql");
// Create a configuration object for our Azure SQL connection parameters
var dbConfig = {
  server: "***", // Use your SQL server name
  database: "***", // Database to connect to
  user: "***", // Use your username
  password: "***", // Use your password
  port: 1433,
  // Since we're on Windows Azure, we need to set the following options
  options: {
    encrypt: true
  }
};

var obj = {};
var res = [];

// This function connects to a SQL server, executes a SELECT statement,
// and displays the results in the console.
function getProducts(callback) {
  // Create connection instance
  var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
  conn.connect()
    // Successfull connection
    .then(function() {
      // Create request instance, passing in connection instance
      var req = new sql.Request(conn);

      // Call mssql's query method passing in params
      req.query("SELECT sp.product_name, count(ss.product_id) as 'quantity' " +
          "FROM smartcoolerstocks ss JOIN smartcoolerproducts sp " +
          "ON sp.product_id = ss.product_id " +
          "GROUP by sp.product_name ")
        .then(function(recordset) {
          conn.close();
          callback(null, recordset.recordset);
          process.exit(1);
        })
        // Handle sql statement execution errors
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          conn.close();
          callback(err, null);
        })
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      conn.close();
      callback(err, null);
    });
}

module.exports = getProducts;
```

And `file2.js`

```js
var myDB2 = require('./sqltest2');
myDB2(function(err, data){
  if( err ) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```